# Create a movie from RGB data stored in Array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, frame, video-processing

I have a set of images stored in an array, created as follow:

```
NewClip = cat(4, NewClip, SingleFrame);
```

where `SingleFrame` is an RGB frame

I am passing the array `NewClip` to a new function to create a movie out of it as follows:

```
    for ThisScene=1:K
    for ThisFrame=1:NewVideoRelativeLength
        NewVideo(:,:,:,TempIndex)=NewClip(:,:,:,ThisScene);
        TempIndex=TempIndex+1;
    end
end
```

in which I iterate to make each frame show for a fixed length...

Doing so I am getting a video with red pixels and blue and yellow and not the actual images in movies. If I do `imshow(NewClip(:,:,:,2))`, I get a correct image so the images are correctly mapped in the array.

Should I do something before setting the frame to the video?

Comment: how do you generate the video from `NewVideo`?

Comment: The video is generated:

NewVideo = zeros([size(SetSizeFrame,1) size(SetSizeFrame,2) 3 NewVideoTotalLength], class(10));

Comment: when you say "getting a video with red pixels..." how do you "get" the video? how do you see it? save it? in what format?

Comment: I just display it using implay(NewVideo,10)

Comment: what is the type of `NewVideo`? is it possible you are trying to view a `double` array with values in range [0..255]? Try `implay( uint8(NewVideo),10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case that your `NewVideo` is a `double` array with values in range `[0..255]`.
try

```
>> implay( uint8(NewVideo), 10 );
```

or

```
>> implay( NewVideo/255, 10 );
```